# Cannot cast LongType to DateType error

Tags: type-conversion, pyspark

(New to PySpark)

I has do lots of search and tried so many different way, I'm posting here my last try:
I have dataframe that looks like:

txn_dt                        datetime64[ns]
id                                int64

I'm trying to use Spark SQL to join txn_dt to another date type and get error type mistmatch, so I'm trying to convert the txn_dt to date using the following code:

```
df = df.withColumn("txn_dt_tmp",df["txn_dt"].cast(DateType())) \
                                        .drop("txn_dt") \
                                        .withColumnRenamed("txn_dt_tmp", "txn_dt")
```

but getting

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'CAST(`txn_dt` AS DATE)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast LongType to DateType;
```

Please help

Comment: Can you post the result of df.take(20)? (Or less if it's very big)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp

df.withColumn('txn_dt',unix_timestamp(txn_dt_tmp,'yyyy-MM-dd').cast("date"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to use `from_unixtime` to get a `timestamp` datatype from your original column, then use `to_date` to convert it to `DateType`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.withColumn("txn_dt", f.to_date(f.from_unixtime(f.col("txn_dt"))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution in Scala, first casting to `Timestamp` and then getting the `Date`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, to_date}

df.withColumn("txn_dt", to_date(col("txn_dt").cast(TimestampType)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert `txn_dt` to "timestamp" and then cast it as a "date" datatype.